# Combining two stored procedures into a single one using some joins

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to Oracle; I have written two stored procedures where they have both different parameters. I would like to combine the queries in that two stored procedures into single query in a single stored procedure, and make sure it supports any criteria.

These are the stored procedures:

```
procedure usp_testsp1(RC1 OUT RCT1,                                
                      in_dep_Id IN number,
                      in_Org_id IN number,
                      in_emp_no IN number) 
is
begin
      select emp.Name as name,select emp.phone as phone,select emp.Race as 
      race
         from employee emp
         JOIN
         Project prj ON
         emp.ProjectId=prj.ProjectId
         JOIN Project_Org Prorg
         ON  prj.ProjectId=Prorg.ProjectId
         JOIN Organization Org1
         ON Prorg.OrgId=Org1.OrgId
         JOIN Organization Org2
         ON emp.OrgId=Org2.OrgId
         AND Org2.OrgType=0
WHERE (upper(emp.emp_No) in (in_emp_No ))
AND Prorg.OrgId=in_Org_id            
AND Org2.OrgId=in_dep_Id                              
end;


procedure usp_testsp2(RC1 OUT RCT1,
                      in_dep_Id IN number,
                      in_Org_id IN number,
                      in_vendor_id IN  raw,
                      in_vendor_startdate IN  date,
                      in_vendor_enddate IN  date)
is
begin
 OPEN RC1 FOR
 select emp.Name as name,select emp.phone as phone,select emp.Race as 
      race
 from
     from employee emp
         JOIN
         Project prj ON
         emp.ProjectId=prj.ProjectId
         JOIN Project_Org Prorg
         ON  prj.ProjectId=Prorg.ProjectId
         JOIN Organization Org1
         ON Prorg.OrgId=Org1.OrgId
         JOIN Organization Org2
         ON emp.OrgId=Org2.OrgId
         AND Org2.OrgType=0
         INNER JOIN vendor_Emp
         ON emp.employeeid=vendor_emp.employeeid
         INNER JOIN Vendor
         ON Vendor.VendorId=Vendor_emp.VendorId
WHERE Prorg.OrgId=in_Org_id            
AND Org2.OrgId=in_dep_Id
AND Vendor.VendorId=in_vendor_id         
AND vendor.StartDate=in_vendor_startdate   AND Vendor.EndDate=in_vendor_enddate    
end;
```

My objective is to combine the queries within these two separate procedures into a single query such that if I combine all the parameters, I have in_emp_no, in_vendor_id, in_vendor_startdate, in_vendor_enddate apart from the common parameters any of the parameters can be null and I want to make sure that those things won't affect the rest of the query even though its not null
For ex i have only in_emp_no ='xxxx' and common inputs rest of the params like 
in_vendor_id etc is null.
I would like to make my query to work even with single paramter to filter the result set
NOTEWithout using Dynamic SQL
Thanks
BJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make columns in the query behave as optional, as far as your join's go, you may need to play with various combinations to make sure everything works.

Sample Table

```
create table sqltest (
empid number,
name  varchar2(10),
orgid number,
depid number,
vendorid number);

insert into sqltest values(1,'BoB',1,1,21);
insert into sqltest values(2,'Chuck',1,1,21);
insert into sqltest values(3,'Mary',1,2,21);
insert into sqltest values(4,'Jane',1,2,22);
insert into sqltest values(5,'Rick',2,1,22);
insert into sqltest values(6,'Samir',2,6,23);
insert into sqltest values(7,'Kirk',3,6,23);
insert into sqltest values(8,'Alex',3,9,23);
commit;
```

Sample Proc

```
create or replace procedure calltest (
   rc1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,
   pempid number,
   porgid number,
   pdepid number,
   pvendorid number)
is 
begin 
open rc1 for 
 select * from sqltest
 where 
  (pempid IS NULL OR empid = pempid) and
  (porgid IS NULL OR orgid = porgid) and
  (pdepid IS NULL OR depid = pdepid) and
  (pvendorid IS NULL OR vendorid = pvendorid);

end;
```

Sample Call

```
set autoprint on;

var vcur refcursor;
declare
begin 
  calltest(rc1=>:vcur,pempid=>NULL,porgid=>1,pdepid=>NULL,pvendorid=>NULL);
  --calltest(rc1=>:vcur,pempid=>NULL,porgid=>1,pdepid=>2,pvendorid=>NULL);
  --calltest(rc1=>:vcur,pempid=>NULL,porgid=>1,pdepid=>2,pvendorid=>22);
  --calltest(rc1=>:vcur,pempid=>NULL,porgid=>NULL,pdepid=>NULL,pvendorid=>23);
end;
```

Sample Output 1

```
VCUR
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPID                                   NAME       ORGID                                   DEPID                                   VENDORID                                
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- 
1                                       BoB        1                                       1                                       21                                      
2                                       Chuck      1                                       1                                       21                                      
3                                       Mary       1                                       2                                       21                                      
4                                       Jane       1                                       2                                       22
```

Sample Output 2

```
VCUR
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPID                                   NAME       ORGID                                   DEPID                                   VENDORID                                
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- 
3                                       Mary       1                                       2                                       21                                      
4                                       Jane       1                                       2                                       22
```

Sample Output 3

```
VCUR
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPID                                   NAME       ORGID                                   DEPID                                   VENDORID                                
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- 
4                                       Jane       1                                       2                                       22
```

Sample Output 4

```
VCUR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPID                                   NAME       ORGID                                   DEPID                                   VENDORID                                
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- 
6                                       Samir      2                                       6                                       23                                      
7                                       Kirk       3                                       6                                       23                                      
8                                       Alex       3                                       9                                       23
```

Comment: will it cause any performance backlog coz i tried to replicate the same thing in my query its thinking alot (pempid IS NULL OR empid = pempid)